# blogdown not inserting archetype when selected

Tags: r, rstudio, blogdown

I have a website setup using hugo and blogdown. I have an archetype setup called `post.md`, located at `/themes/silhouette-hugo/archetypes/post.md`, that looks like this:

```
---
title: "{{ replace .Name "-" " " | title }}"
date: {{ .Date }}
draft: true
categories:
  - Software Development
tags:
  - Untagged
featureImage: images/nelson_lakes_photo.jpg
---

""`<!--more-->`""
```

I went through the New Post addin in RStudio:
[image]

However the markdown file I got didn't include the archetype style

```
---
title: test
author: Conor Neilson
date: '2021-08-22'
slug: []
categories: []
tags: []
---
```

This used to work fine, it's only stopped working in the last few months.

Hugo version is 0.87.0, blogdown version 1.4.3.

Source code for my website is [here](https://github.com/condwanaland/Still-the-Data)

Comment: Sounds like a bug of blogdown. I'll see if I can fix it soon. BTW, I strongly recommend that you pin the Hugo version in your `.Rprofile`---`blogdown::check_site()` will tell you how: https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/a-quick-example.html#when-in-doubt-run-blogdowncheck_site

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, have now added this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I just fixed this bug](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/b22bc9b5cecf0af32694d909b5d20e0477aa3e27) in blogdown. You may try the dev version:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

(Remember to restart R)

Comment: Thanks Yihui. I've updated to blogdown v1.4.4, but still seeing the same issue. Only difference I'm seeing now is that the yaml includes `draft: yes`

Comment: Sorry I only tested the function `blogdown::new_post()` yesterday. The "New Post" addin seems to be still problematic. I can reproduce your problem with the addin, and will try to fix it soon. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed now. Please reinstall the dev version. Thanks!